# what's a good use case for the custom object administration privilege?

Tags: force.com, security

This is a privilege for delegated users, which lets them add/update/delete fields, page layouts, etc at the object level. But it also gives them the ability to delete an object.

how do you leverage such a privilege? or how did SF think that this would be a good thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picklist values mostly? Useful when the alternative is to have 3 IT tickets / week "Please add following values to Cities picklist because we cannot make new Opportunities" ;) I'm aware there are better solutions (opt-in for Country/State picklists pilot, a lookup object) but some things were done before you came to certain organisation, you have to work with what's there and there's never enough time to refactor.

Depending how powerful your local power users are - I've seen orgs with users in multiple countries and local IT / key business person responsible for Salesforce knew how to make workflow rules, validations etc. themselves. Doesn't really help much because eventually they need to notify "corporate IT" what they did anyway so we can download change to Force IDE / SVN / push to sandboxes to make sure it's not overwritten during deployments. Also such guerilla changes on production tend to be frowned upon.

---

I've used the whole set of Delegated Administration thing in full sandbox / during User Acceptance Testing. You grant your tester right to "login as" Roles that have to be tested + if he's skilled enough he can add picklist values, maybe a formula or 2 if complex reporting needs arise and that can speed up the testing significantly.

But I'm not convinced it's useful to have it enabled in production. And the right to delete object won't help them much if there's Apex/Visualforce/Formula that relies on it ;)

Comment: Granting UAT/QAT that type of access in the QA environment makes AWESOME sense! that would really help the QA process!   I love that idea, so long as the guy knows enough!

Answer (score 0):

We used this feature for cases for customer service.  They manage a couple of dependent pick lists across record types, statuses, and sometimes also temporary checkbox fields for reporting needs where we don't want to mess with the normal categorization but they do want to "tally" something as they come in and see a report of it.